# Click function is not working in my web application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal for `signup` and `signin`. Inside `signup` modal when I want to go to `signin` modal from here and click to `signin` button then `signup` modal will hide and `signin` modal will appear. From same procedure happen to `signin` modal.

But here these `signin` or `signup` button inside the modal haven't work.

I have also used `e.preventDefault();` inside the `js` function but still doesn't work.

I don't find out the script problem since I am not good in JS.

**signin modal**

```
<div class="modal fade bs-modal-sm" id="signin_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <br>
                            <div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
                                <ul id="signin_myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                                  <center><li id="signin_Modal_tab" class="active"><a href="#signin" data-toggle="tab">SIGN IN</a></li></center>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="signin">

                                    <span id="student_signin_error"></span>

                                    <form class="form-horizontal" id="signin_form">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
                                    <fieldset>
                                    <!-- Sign In Form -->

                                    <!-- Email input-->
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input required="" id="signin_email" name="email" class="col-ld-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="input-medium">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <div class="controls">
                                        <input required="" id="signin_password" name="password" class="col-ld-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-medium">
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- Button -->
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                      <div class="controls modal_submit_button">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="signin_form_submit_button">Sign In</button>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>

                                     <div class="control-group">
                                      <div class="controls modal_submit_button">
                                        Don't have an account ! Click here to 
                                        <a href="#" class="signup_from_signin_modal">Sign Up</a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <center>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </center>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.signup_from_signin_modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#signin_Modal').modal('hide');
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
});
```

If I called `alert()` inside that script function it will work.
But `$('#signin_Modal').modal('hide');` this function doesn't work.

Anybody Help please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `signin_modal` != `signin_Modal`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen....sorry brother...It's my mistake....I ddn't place the correct modal name. very silly mistake...sorry

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen....do I remove the question now ? Cause it is typo mistake not functional

Comment: You can, as a typo it won’t probably help anyone else here. And don’t worry, these things happen to everyone

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen...ok brother...But feel interesting because already got 10 points by this typo mistake ... hahaha....

Comment: @Raff and one day it will be forcibly closed because it was just a **Typo** and you will be wondering why you lost those reputation points.

Comment: @N69S... Thanks for the advice.... I will be more careful about these issues.

Answer (score -1):

You have accidentally in your jQuery selector put `signin_Modal` ,

instead you should be trying to select `signin_modal` .

This is just something that happens from time to time in coding, happy hacking :)

Comment: @Chizzele...thanks brother. I have already figure that out. Thanks for your concern